# exim variable for domain

Tags: email-server, exim, rate-limiting

So i've been reading a lot about exim, however there are some variables which are showing an empty string on my server and therefore they are not working with my rate limit conditions.

For instance I have tried:
$sender_host_address
$domain

So here is my condition:

```
acl_check_smtp:
        deny message = Sender rate overlimit - $sender_rate / $sender_rate_period
        ratelimit = 300 / 1h / per_rcpt / leaky / $sender_address
        accept
```

However, this is just limiting outgoing emails to one single email address, so people can switch between accounts and send 300 emails per hour per each account, I'd like to limit that to 300 per domain.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sender_address_domain` which should contain the domain portion of the sender address.

Expansion variables are listed in [chapter 11](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html) of the [Exim Specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html).